# Verifying User Certificate with Root Certificate Java

Tags: java, openssl, root-certificate

I'm trying to verify the certificates provided by the users to my tomcat website (during mutual/client/certificate authentication).

Now I know that verifying the certificates manually may not be required as I suppose the browser does it before prompting for a certificate to the user.
However, I still tried to do it and I have a few questions about it.

Please go through my process of creating the certificates as well as verifying them.

I am generating the Certificates as below:

```bash
# Generate Root Key
openssl genrsa -des3 -out root.key 2048

# Create a self signed Root Certificate
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key rootCA.key -sha256 -days 1024 -out root.crt

# Generate User Key
openssl genrsa -out user.key 2048

# Generate User CSR
openssl req -new -key user.key -out user.csr

# Generate User Certificate and sign with Root Key
openssl x509 -req -in user.csr -CA root.crt -CAkey root.key -CAcreateserial -out user.crt -days 500 -sha256
```

Now I import the `user.crt`, `user.key` and the `root.crt` in a `user.p12` keystore like so:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out user.p12 -inkey user.key -in user.cert -certfile root.crt
```

`user.p12` gets distributed to the users who will be using the site.

I imported the `root.crt` to my "truststore" which is used by tomcat.

Now, when I try to verify the certificate provided by the users, I try to do the following:

```
File file = new File(keystorePath);
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
keyStore.load(is, keyStorePass.toCharArray());

PKIXParameters params = new PKIXParameters(keyStore);

Set<TrustAnchor> trustAnchors = params.getTrustAnchors();

List<Certificate> certificates = trustAnchors.stream()
        .map(TrustAnchor::getTrustedCert)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

Boolean certVerified = Boolean.FALSE;
for (Certificate cert : certificates){
    try {
        userCertificate.verify(cert.getPublicKey());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        continue;
    }
    LOGGER.info("Verified User Certificate.");
    certVerified = Boolean.TRUE;
    break;
}
```

This seems to work fine. However, my question is that since `user.crt` is created with `root.crt`, shouldn't the following code:

```java
userCertificate.verify(cert.getPublicKey());
```

work like this?

```java
cert.verify(userCertificate.getPublicKey());
```

My questions are as follows:

1. Am I correct in assuming that I do not need verify user certificates in my code?
2. If the `user.crt` is created with `root.crt`, why is `user.crt` used to verify `root.crt` and not the other way round?
3. Am I completely dense and missing something important and all my logic is incorrect?

Comment: 1. The only thing you're verifying is user certificates. 2. `root.crt` *is* used to verify `user.crt`. 3. I think you're just reading the method wrong: `cert1.verify(cert2.getPublicKey())` means use `cert2` to verify `cert1`. See the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/cert/Certificate.html#verify-java.security.PublicKey-).

Comment: 1. Yes you don't need to verify the client cert; the SSL/TLS implementation in your server already does, either the Java implementation JSSE if you configure that way, or OpenSSL if you (install and) configure 'native/APR'. That's the whole _point_ of SSL/TLS client authentication, namely that it authenticates the client.